# VS6 C++ upgrade to VS2013 gives LNK2038 MT_StaticRelease / MD_DynamicRelease errors

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, mfc, static-libraries

I have been handed a 'vintage' project built using VS6 C++ to try and get running in VS2013 (no functional changes required, just get it building and running).

The final part that I cannot get to work is that the solution contains an MetaDASTest.exe which uses MFC in a shared DLL and the Runtime Library is set to Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD).

When building MetaDASTest.exe it is using MetaLibrary which is a Static Library (.lib) not using MFC (Use Standard Windows Libraries) and the Runtime Library is set to Multi-Threaded (/MT).

The output given when building the MetaDASTest.exe project is as follows:

```
Searching ..\..\Deployment\Release\MetaLibrary.lib:
Found "public: __thiscall Unipower::MetaLibrary::CSchemaSingleton::~CSchemaSingleton(void)" (??1CSchemaSingleton@MetaLibrary@Unipower@@QAE@XZ)
Referenced in MetaDASTest.obj
Referenced in MetaDASTestDlg.obj
Loaded MetaLibrary.lib(SchemaSingleton.obj)
MetaLibrary.lib(SchemaSingleton.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in MetaDASTestDlg.obj
```

This all builds in VS6 with no modification... why does the RuntimeLibrary have to match between the calling exe and the called lib in VS2013? have I missed a project property setting that has not been set correctly through using the upgrade wizard?

Comment: I don't know but I always had trouble getting MFC working statically even when using VS6... did you try changing between static and dynamic linking?

Comment: You are linking code that was built with conflicting compiler settings.  Mixing /MT with /MD compiled code normally causes many very hard to diagnose runtime problems.  You got away with it, that's technically possible.  But today, this is checked by the linker and it will complain.  You'll have to fix the settings, compile *everything* with /MD.

Comment: Searching around it seems that indeed we can no longer mix the Runtime Libraries and it is now enforced. This doesn't fix my issue, this creates a mountain of work as I have 30+ Runtime Library violations which I now have to convert to /MD.

Comment: Mixing static and dynamic CRT is asking for trouble. If you allocate memory in one module and free it in another module, they must use the same heap manager. This can also happen implicitly, e.g.by passing a vector or string.